# How do I line up series points on a compare intervals graph?

Tags: highcharts

I am having this issue with both line and column graphs.

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brookssh/tzhoka34/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
      renderTo: 'chartContainer',
      height: 595,
      width: 1100,
      type: '',
      defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
      backgroundColor: null,
      reflow: false,
      shadow: true,
      marginLeft: 60,
      spacingTop: 5,
      marginTop: 70,
      width: 1100,
      spacingBottom: 100,
  },
  legend: {
      enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
      enabled: false
  },
  title: {
      text: "Daily Utility Demand Comparison",
      style: {
          color: '#484a4a',
          fontSize: '22px',
          fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
  },
  subtitle: {
      text: "<span style=\"color:#484a4a; font-weight:bold;\">Main Hydro - </span><br><span style=\"color:grey\">Tuesday, January 01 2013 12:00 AM and Wednesday, January 01 2014 12:00 AM</span>",
      y: 36
  },
  xAxis: [{
      title: {
          text: 'Time',
          style: {
              color: '#0063A2',
              fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
              fontWeight: 'bold'
          }
      },
      type: 'datetime',
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          second: '%H:%M:%S',
          minute: '%H:%M',
          hour: '%I:%M %p',
          day: '%b %d',
          month: '%B',
          year: '%Y'
      },
      plotBands: []
  }, {
      labels: {
          enabled: false
      },
      lineWidth: 0,
      tickWidth: 0
  }],
  yAxis: {
      title: {
          text: 'Demand (kW)',
          style: {
              color: '#0063A2',
              fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
              fontWeight: 'bold'
          }
      },
      plotLines: [{
          value: 0,
          width: 2,
          color: '#000000'
      }],
      min: 0
  },

  tooltip: {
      formatter: function () {
          if (this.series.name == "Tuesday, January 01 2013 Demand|14657.85 kWh") var fontColor = "0063A2";
          else var fontColor = "A21500";
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y - %I:%M %P  :  ', this.x) + '<b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + ' kW' + '</b>';
      }
  },
  plotOptions: {
      spline: {
          animation: {
              duration: 1500
          },
          marker: {
              enabled: false,
              states: {
                  hover: {
                      enabled: true,
                      symbol: 'circle',
                      radius: 5,
                      lineWidth: 1
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },


  series: [{
      name: "Tuesday, January 01 2013 Demand|14657.85 kWh",
      zIndex: 2,
      color: '#0063A2',
      xAxis: 0,
      data: [
          [1356999300000, 430.20000],
          [1357000200000, 414.00000],
          [1357001100000, 410.40000],
          [1357002000000, 414.00000],
          [1357002900000, 421.20000],
          [1357003800000, 417.60000],
          [1357004700000, 410.40000],
          [1357005600000, 412.20000],
          [1357006500000, 408.60000],
          [1357007400000, 408.60000],
          [1357008300000, 406.80000],
          [1357009200000, 403.20000],
          [1357010100000, 408.60000],
          [1357011000000, 410.40000],
          [1357011900000, 408.60000],
          [1357012800000, 423.00000],
          [1357013700000, 419.40000],
          [1357014600000, 405.00000],
          [1357015500000, 414.00000],
          [1357016400000, 415.80000],
          [1357017300000, 518.40000],
          [1357018200000, 511.20000],
          [1357019100000, 550.80000],
          [1357020000000, 541.80000],
          [1357020900000, 640.80000],
          [1357021800000, 646.20000],
          [1357022700000, 685.80000],
          [1357023600000, 693.00000],
          [1357024500000, 714.60000],
          [1357025400000, 723.60000],
          [1357026300000, 727.20000],
          [1357027200000, 727.20000],
          [1357028100000, 747.00000],
          [1357029000000, 730.80000],
          [1357029900000, 738.00000],
          [1357030800000, 739.80000],
          [1357031700000, 730.80000],
          [1357032600000, 732.60000],
          [1357033500000, 723.60000],
          [1357034400000, 725.40000],
          [1357035300000, 730.80000],
          [1357036200000, 729.00000],
          [1357037100000, 732.60000],
          [1357038000000, 729.00000],
          [1357038900000, 727.20000],
          [1357039800000, 730.80000],
          [1357040700000, 729.00000],
          [1357041600000, 730.80000],
          [1357042500000, 730.80000],
          [1357043400000, 738.00000],
          [1357044300000, 727.20000],
          [1357045200000, 730.80000],
          [1357046100000, 723.60000],
          [1357047000000, 725.40000],
          [1357047900000, 732.60000],
          [1357048800000, 725.40000],
          [1357049700000, 729.00000],
          [1357050600000, 730.80000],
          [1357051500000, 734.40000],
          [1357052400000, 730.80000],
          [1357053300000, 732.60000],
          [1357054200000, 727.20000],
          [1357055100000, 736.20000],
          [1357056000000, 732.60000],
          [1357056900000, 729.00000],
          [1357057800000, 732.60000],
          [1357058700000, 730.80000],
          [1357059600000, 736.20000],
          [1357060500000, 747.00000],
          [1357061400000, 730.80000],
          [1357062300000, 730.80000],
          [1357063200000, 750.60000],
          [1357064100000, 714.60000],
          [1357065000000, 702.00000],
          [1357065900000, 703.80000],
          [1357066800000, 714.60000],
          [1357067700000, 613.80000],
          [1357068600000, 586.80000],
          [1357069500000, 583.20000],
          [1357070400000, 579.60000],
          [1357071300000, 558.00000],
          [1357072200000, 558.00000],
          [1357073100000, 552.60000],
          [1357074000000, 554.40000],
          [1357074900000, 538.20000],
          [1357075800000, 516.60000],
          [1357076700000, 513.00000],
          [1357077600000, 523.80000],
          [1357078500000, 518.40000],
          [1357079400000, 516.60000],
          [1357080300000, 518.40000],
          [1357081200000, 514.80000],
          [1357082100000, 464.40000],
          [1357083000000, 448.20000],
          [1357083900000, 453.60000],
          [1357084800000, 459.00000]
      ]
  }, {
      name: "Wednesday, January 01 2014 Demand|12673.80 kWh",
      zIndex: 1,
      color: '#A21500',
      xAxis: 1,
      data: [
          [1388535300000, 480.60000],
          [1388536200000, 469.80000],
          [1388537100000, 475.20000],
          [1388538000000, 475.20000],
          [1388538900000, 473.40000],
          [1388539800000, 477.00000],
          [1388540700000, 455.40000],
          [1388541600000, 390.60000],
          [1388542500000, 394.20000],
          [1388543400000, 396.00000],
          [1388544300000, 403.20000],
          [1388545200000, 401.40000],
          [1388546100000, 403.20000],
          [1388547000000, 401.40000],
          [1388547900000, 399.60000],
          [1388548800000, 396.00000],
          [1388549700000, 405.00000],
          [1388550600000, 475.20000],
          [1388551500000, 469.80000],
          [1388552400000, 475.20000],
          [1388553300000, 504.00000],
          [1388554200000, 518.40000],
          [1388555100000, 543.60000],
          [1388556000000, 534.60000],
          [1388556900000, 568.80000],
          [1388557800000, 572.40000],
          [1388558700000, 595.80000],
          [1388559600000, 599.40000],
          [1388560500000, 590.40000],
          [1388561400000, 579.60000],
          [1388562300000, 581.40000],
          [1388563200000, 577.80000],
          [1388564100000, 585.00000],
          [1388565000000, 585.00000],
          [1388565900000, 574.20000],
          [1388566800000, 581.40000],
          [1388567700000, 577.80000],
          [1388568600000, 574.20000],
          [1388569500000, 567.00000],
          [1388570400000, 574.20000],
          [1388571300000, 581.40000],
          [1388572200000, 576.00000],
          [1388573100000, 567.00000],
          [1388574000000, 599.40000],
          [1388574900000, 604.80000],
          [1388575800000, 603.00000],
          [1388576700000, 592.20000],
          [1388577600000, 586.80000],
          [1388578500000, 604.80000],
          [1388579400000, 613.80000],
          [1388580300000, 563.40000],
          [1388581200000, 527.40000],
          [1388582100000, 522.00000],
          [1388583000000, 522.00000],
          [1388583900000, 518.40000],
          [1388584800000, 507.60000],
          [1388585700000, 502.20000],
          [1388586600000, 513.00000],
          [1388587500000, 525.60000],
          [1388588400000, 504.00000],
          [1388589300000, 511.20000],
          [1388590200000, 500.40000],
          [1388591100000, 511.20000],
          [1388592000000, 514.80000],
          [1388592900000, 507.60000],
          [1388593800000, 516.60000],
          [1388594700000, 523.80000],
          [1388595600000, 522.00000],
          [1388596500000, 543.60000],
          [1388597400000, 601.20000],
          [1388598300000, 597.60000],
          [1388599200000, 588.60000],
          [1388600100000, 576.00000],
          [1388601000000, 588.60000],
          [1388601900000, 597.60000],
          [1388602800000, 595.80000],
          [1388603700000, 554.40000],
          [1388604600000, 556.20000],
          [1388605500000, 559.80000],
          [1388606400000, 558.00000],
          [1388607300000, 554.40000],
          [1388608200000, 554.40000],
          [1388609100000, 541.80000],
          [1388610000000, 545.40000],
          [1388610900000, 536.40000],
          [1388611800000, 529.20000],
          [1388612700000, 527.40000],
          [1388613600000, 527.40000],
          [1388614500000, 534.60000],
          [1388615400000, 534.60000],
          [1388616300000, 534.60000],
          [1388617200000, 525.60000],
          [1388618100000, 496.80000],
          [1388619000000, 493.20000],
          [1388619900000, 495.00000],
          [1388620800000, 502.20000]
      ]
  }]
});
```

Comment: Do you always have a specific amount of time on the x-axis? Like 1 day, for both series?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified a `type` for your second `xAxis`. This causes it to default to `linear` and not line up with your first `xAxis` which is `datetime`.

Just add `type: 'datetime'` to your second x-axis and the series should line up, since you already have the points equally spaced out in the two series.

See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzhoka34/1/) of how it looks.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I can't believe I missed that.